# NameError: uninitialized constant Carrierwave (Deploy to Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, postgresql, heroku

I'm using Carrierwave to upload images but I having some issues: This is the log from heroku:

```
 Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.2276
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Carrierwave
/app/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:443:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
WARNING: Toolbelt v3.36.4 update available.
```

Here are my files:

carrier_wave.rb:

```
    if Rails.env.production?
    Carrierwave.configure do |config|
        config.fog_credentials = {
            :provider => 'AWS',
            :aws_access_key_id => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
            :aws_secrety_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY']
        }
        config.fog_directory = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
    end 
end
```

Application.rb:

```
    require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require 'carrierwave'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MagicRecipes
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/uploaders)

    config.serve_static_files = true

    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
  end
end

picture_uploader.rb

    class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base


  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  process resize_to_limit: [600, 600]


  if Rails.env.production?
    storage :fog
  else
    storage :file

  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end


    def extension_white_list
      %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
    end



end
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.4.1'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.59.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.7'
gem 'pry', '~> 0.10.1'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap', '~> 1.0.1'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.10.0'
```

`enter code here`gem 'mini_magick', '~> 3.8.0'
`enter code here`gem 'fog', '~> 1.23.0'
`enter code here`gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

I have the gems and versions installed in my gemfile.

I don't know what is the problem, I did a entire research but I can solve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you initializing Carrierwave? please include your Gemfile

Comment: There is a typo in constant name - correct name is CarrierWave. Check documentation https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your carrier_wave.rb file, you have a typo in the name. Change Carrierwave to CarrierWave. As in [documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave.rb)